# Movie about driving a woman crazy to gain inheritance

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie roughly 15 years ago, although it was in black and white.  It's about a woman(call her Molly for now, though I doubt that was her name) who lives alone, until some relative(sister or cousin, I think) comes in.  Throughout the movie, the relative is trying to convince the Molly that she's (Molly) is crazy.  If I recall, the motive was to have her committed or something so she can gain some sort of inheritance.  I vaguely remember one scene where Molly is in a room, and a decapitated head rolls across the floor.  It may have been a skull, or full head, I can't remember.  Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

After some more discussion with the wife, we've come to the conclusion that the relative of "Molly" is a female, and that we THINK it takes place in a southern state.

Comment: You can always [help yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_black-and-white_films_produced_since_1970) if you want to!

Comment: @Mistu4u I've looked at that list with the wife for a week, but we believe it's not on that list.  So maybe it's older than the 70's?

Comment: But you yourself said the movie is not older than 15yrs (_or 20 yrs for the sake of "roughness"_)! Going back more than '70s would make it self-contradictory!

Comment: No, I said I SAW it 15 years ago.  Not that it wasn't older than 15 years.  It could have been from the 30's for all I know.

Comment: Your movie is proving elusive. Anything else you might remember? Do you think it was American? Was your impression that it was a B-movie or was it well acted? Any thoughts on the time period for the story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could this possibly be [Hush... Hush, Sweet Charlotte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hush..._Hush,_Sweet_Charlotte), which takes place on a plantation in Louisiana, and has a beheading and a cousin named Miriam?

Comment: YES!  ZOMG YES!  After seeing your answer, I watched it last night, and this is it!  TYVM!

Answer (score 7):

Could it be *[The Screaming Skull](https://www.youtube.com/movie?v=L-DsKGrP8ho&feature=mv_sr)*, a black and white film from 1958?

> For reasons best known to local TV programmers, the modest shocker The
>   Screaming Skull was telecast on what seemed to be a daily basis in the
>   1960s. The hero-villain is Eric (played by John Hudson, who later
>   billed himself as William Hudson), the husband of neurotic
>   millionairess Jenni Peggy Webber. By strategically placing miniature
>   skulls all over the house, Eric hopes to drive Jenni into madness so
>   that he can take control of her fortune. The police suspect that
>   Mickey the gardener Alex Nicol, who also directed the film) is the man
>   behind the campaign of terror, but the truth finally surfaces in the
>   last reel, wherein Eric gets what's coming to him-and more besides.

[image]

Comment: I was discussing it with my wife, and we're certain that the relative who was trying to drive "Molly" crazy was a female.  So this wouldn't fit.  But very nice try.